# Unable to connect to Unity 5

Tags: unity-game-engine

I read the topic rules and I figured this can be an appropriate question to ask you guys.

I am currently using Unity 5, it has been letting me use the program in offline mode, but when I want to access the asset store it stops me from doing this. Ive tried everything and dont know what todo now, I need to use the asset store.

The exact error: https://gyazo.com/98985cf1f21f016bcf775b70bee01c18

I'm running on a windows computer, I do infact have windows fire wall, and a virus protector(norton)

What should I do from here?

Comment: are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Is there anyway you can screenshare on join.me(a screenshare program) to help me

Comment: best thing you can do is create a thread at http://forum.unity3d.com/threads where you meet many professional unity developers.

Comment: I tried and got ignored. Could you maybe help i need to use the asset store

Comment: can you log outside(by webbrowser) and then open unity through it?

Comment: What do you mean? I can log on unity using web browser. I have a virus protector and windows firewall if that means anything too

Comment: Can we talk somewhere this site is getting mad at me for having conversations

Comment: looks like i'm having a problem as well :O ,this haven't happened before, but try this

1.go to random asset like this through web browser
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/18022
2.Then youll find a button saying "Open in Unity",just click it.
3.Then start a sepearate project.
4.fill login details and download